# Specifying variables in cor.matrix

Tags: r, deducer

Trying to use `Deducer`'s `cor.matrix` to create a correlation matrix to be used in `ggcorplot`.

Trying to run a simple example. Only explicitly specifying the variable names in the data works:

```
cor.mat<-cor.matrix(variables=d(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length,Petal.Width),
                      data=iris[1:4],test=cor.test,method='p')
```

But I'd like it to simple use all columns in the provided data.

This:

```
cor.mat<-cor.matrix(data=iris[1:4],test=cor.test,method='p')
```

throws an error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : argument is missing, with no default
```

This:

```
cor.mat<-cor.matrix(variables=d(as.name(paste(colnames(iris)[1:4]),collapse=",")),
                    data=iris[1:4],test=cor.test,method='p')

Error in as.name(paste(colnames(iris)[1:4]), collapse = ",") : 
  unused argument (collapse = ",")
```

So is there any way to tell `variables` to use all columns in `data` without explicitly specifying them?

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the function is `variables =`, which is required but you did not specify (you had `data =`).  Try

```
cor.mat <- cor.matrix(variables = iris[1:4], test = cor.test, method = 'p')
ggcorplot(cor.mat, data=iris)
```

[image]

Comment: @dan did this solve your issue? If so, please consider upvoting / accepting the answer.